# What are the invertible elements of the $K[X]$ ring where $K$ is a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

What are the invertible elements of the $K[X]$ ring where $K$ is  a field?

I know that in a field all the elements are invertible but I'm having trouble linking $K$ and $K[X]$

Comment: Hint: If a polynomial is invertible of degree $n$, what can the degree of the inverse be?

Answer (score 4):

If we have two nonzero polynomials $f$ and $g$ of degrees $n$ and $m$ then consider the leading terms, say $aX^n$ and $bX^m$. The product $fg$ must have leading term $abX^{n+m}$. Since $K$ is a field we can't have $ab=0$ and so $fg$ has degree $n+m$. Thus $fg$ can't be $1$ unless both $f$ and $g$ have degree $0$.

Conversely it's clear that every nonzero polynomial of degree $0$ is invertible.